# How can i read in a series of bytes in java and store them?

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles

I am trying to parse a data file header that will look something like this:
7B 01 2C 00 00 EA 60 2C 03 2C 56 
where all values are in Hex.
I am currently using a scanner scan, and doing something like:

```
if(scan.getNextByte()==0x7B) {do work}
```

This is throwing an inputMismatchException

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
```

I think my question is what am i doing wrong here, but i am also curious if there is a better way to do this then what i am currently doing.  I need to parse based on each individual byte which is why im not reading in an entire line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

nextByte() expects a byte (-128 to 127) in decimal.

I suggest reading a word and parsing it as hex e.g.

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next(), 16);
```

or you can use

```
int num = scanner.nextInt(16);
```

This is not a signed byte as I assume you expect FF == 255 not -1.